# using shallow compare isEqual in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

in somewhere you did

```
this.setState({ tableTH: this.state.tableTH === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc' })
```

and you want to do another action, like recall the api, how would u do it? There's 2 way, the first one is to use the second argument of setState method, like this

```
this.setState({ tableTH: this.state.tableTH === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc' }, () => this.callAPI())
```

but this can be messy says you have many many setState, this make ur code hard to read if the logic is complicated.

Use componentDidUpdate

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if(!isEqual(prevState.tableTH, this.state.tableTH)){ //let's assume tableTH state is an object
      this.callAPI() 
   }
}
```

Above code worked the same, assume tableTH is a object this will still work. But is it ok to use isEqual from lodash? Will this make the operation expensive? What about nested Object? Deep equal comparison will look like this

```
_.differenceWith(prevState.tableTH, this.state.tableTH, _.isEqual);
```

Comment: If you are concerned about the cost of using lodash, you should look into how expensive that method is versus manually comparing those values yourself.  If it is accomplishing *exactly* what you want it to accomplish, and is fairly inexpensive, then don't worry about it.  If you want to be exact, write the smallest possible function to do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) does not accept any args. So your example seems incorrect. You need to use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), if you want to compare to see if the component should render.

Comment: Also, your question says `componentDidUpdate`, but that lifecycle method is called after the render. I would advise to read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to get a proper handle of how the lifecycle methods work.

Comment: @Hozefa it is my mistake, I don't mean componentDidMount, it should be `componentDidUpdate `. I edited the question.

Comment: @JasonSpradlin compare myself using normal `===` is ok but how about nested object / arrays?

Comment: You would have to loop over the values of the array/object and compare those, and then also (potentially) loop over the values of the children of any of those original values.  You would end up either creating a recursive function to test with infinite depth (goes as deep as it needs until everything has been reached) or a shallow compare function which only checks the immediate children.  It all depends on the data you're actually trying to make a comparison of.

Comment: @JasonSpradlin I know the logic, but is that what would you do in real world application? Just a simple example will do, says user clicked on a table th to sort a column, change the state then call the api, how would u do it?

Comment: In a real world application, I would know what the data looks like, and would make a decision based on that.  Usually, I would argue that a developer should default to an existing, tested, and refined library before rewriting the same functionality themselves, where they could potentially be introducing bugs that the library has already resolved themselves.  I could write this function, but if the library already does it, I won't spend time on it, and will instead spend time on something that is unique to my project, for which I can't just use a library.